# What is a good PHP script I can use as a poll?

Tags: php

What is a good free PHP script to use as a poll for a website? I'd need a simple script to show on the web page with the standard multiple option vote + bar chart graph. Also an admin interface with add / edit / delete poll would be required.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Advanced Poll](http://www.proxy2.de/scripts.php) a fair bit, and found it to be pretty good, and do pretty much exactly what you described.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

[Presto Poll](http://prestopoll.sourceforge.net/) is somewhat popular. It supports both databases and flat files for data storage and has a simple but thorough admin section.